# How to normalize the input email?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, email-validation, express-validator

I was working with `express-validator` when i encountered that i used normalize email for validation of email while signing up so i stored the normalized email to server.

Validation code:

```
router.post(
  "/signup",
  [
    check("name").not().isEmpty(),
    check("email").normalizeEmail().isEmail(),
    check("password").isLength({ min: 6, max: 15 }),
  ],
  userController.signupUser
);
```

Input email: `abc.123@mail.com`

normalized email: `abc123@gmail.com` (storing in db)

Now the problem is when working on login the input email doesn't matches and shows invalid credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After researching and observing I noticed that the code which was used at the time of signing up can be used to normalize email at the time of login, I just had to add:

```
 router.post("/login",[check('email').normalizeEmail()], userController.loginUser);
```

After adding the email was converting to normalized one and can be used directly from requests.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to pass options inside `normalizeEmail ()` in your validation chain, in a middleware:

```
normalizeEmail({ gmail_remove_dots: false })
```

Comment: Good solution, but you made a typo `{gmail_remove_dots: false }` and for forgot to include source https://github.com/validatorjs/validator.js#sanitizers

Answer (score -1):

You cannot remove any `. or _` since it's part of the user's e-mail.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) and example of validating an email address

Comment: can you suggest a solution for the library i am using,because i intentionally want to have a normalized email at backend.

Comment: I give a short read on the [docs](https://express-validator.github.io/docs/validation-chain-api.html) it seems you shoud only use `isEmail()` not `normalizeEmail()`.
I recommend to simple use [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) to get it lower case

Comment: but i want to use normalize email so that some other person cannot make account with  email of same signature.

Comment: Well, that should be done on your table making it unique or checking it manually.